# Two limits about "asymptotic slope"

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization

Given a differentiable function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, suppose limit

> $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{{h_1} \to \infty } \frac{{f(x + {h_1}{\mathbf{v}}) - f(x)}}{{{h_1}}}$ ... (1)

exists for some $x\in  \Bbb R^n, {\bf v} \in \Bbb R^n$. My text book says this is kind of asymptotic slope at point $x$ to direction $\bf v$.

Define the derivative of $f$ at point $x$ along direction $\bf v$ as

> $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\mathbf{v}}}}(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h_2 \to 0} \frac{{f(x + h_2{\mathbf{v}}) - f(x)}}{h_2}$ ... (2)

Since $f$ is differentiable, then $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\mathbf{v}}}}(x)$ exists for any $x$ and any $\bf v$. Now I am thinking about the following limit is also some "asymptotic slope"

> $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{{h_1} \to \infty } \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial {\mathbf{v}}}}(x + {h_1}{\mathbf{v}}) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{{h_1} \to \infty } \mathop {\lim }\limits_{{h_2} \to 0} \frac{{f(x + {h_1}{\mathbf{v}} + {h_2}{\mathbf{v}}) - f(x + {h_1}{\mathbf{v}})}}{{{h_2}}}$ ... (3)

I think there must be some relation between limit (1) and limit (3), and **I think possibly** "limit (1) = $\|{\bf{v}}\| \times$ limit (3)" (e.g. for $f(x)=x$ this proposition is true). But I have trouble prove the proposition. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the limit exist ?
Take one sequence $(h_n)$ converging to $0$ such that
$h_1=h_n, h_2=h_n$ and then $h_1=h_n,h_2=-h_n$.
Now compute the limit in both cases as $n\rightarrow \infty$,
you should have different limit no ?

Comment: @Smilia Thanks for comment but I could not understand. In the problem, $h_1 \to \infty $ and $h_2 \to 0$

Comment: oh my bad .... :/ time to sleep, sorry